# Python requests library Exception handling

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, http-status-code-503

I am creating a download service using the python requests library (See [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)) to download data from another server. The problem is that sometimes I get a `503 error` and I need to display an appropriate message. See sample code below:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('http://mycustomserver.org/download')
```

I can check from `response.status_code` and get the `status code = 200`.
But how do I `try/catch` for a specific error, in this case, I want to be able to detect `503 error` and handle them appropriately.

How do I do that?

Comment: Look at the code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kennethreitz/requests/master/requests/exceptions.py, there are many http error codes, there is no exception class for each, instead there is one for all http errors

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not do

```
class MyException(Exception);
   def __init__(self, error_code, error_msg):
       self.error_code = error_code
       self.error_msg = error_msg

import requests
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('http://mycustomserver.org/download')

if response.status_code == 503:
    raise MyException(503, "503 error code")
```

**Edit:**

It seems that requests library will also raise an Exception for you using `response.raise_for_status()`

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://google.com/admin')
<Response [404]>
>>> response = requests.get('https://google.com/admin')
>>> response.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 638, in raise_for_status
    raise http_error
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

**Edit2:**

Wrap you `raise_for_status` with the following `try/except`

```
try:
    if response.status_code == 503:
        response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e: 
    if e.response.status_code == 503:
        #handle your 503 specific error
```

Comment: I was looking at [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) part and wondering which will enable me to catch the `503 error`. Thanks though.

Comment: I see - added the relevant `try/except` block.

Comment: @MartinKonecny  - How do you check for all errors instead of listing each one by one. ? i.e. http error, bad url error, ssl certificate error, etc.... is there a general exception handler that cover all errors? Or I am just going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: @Stryker You could can catch all exceptions using `except e:` and then over time put in multiple more specific `catch`es to have a unique behaviour for each situation (if you need that of course)

Answer (score 4):

You might as well do this:

```
try:
    s = requests.Session()
    response = requests.get('http://mycustomserver.org/download')
    if response.status_code == 503:
        response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print "oops something unexpected happened!"
```

`response.raise_for_status()` raises a `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` and here we are only calling `response.raise_for_status()` if the status code is equal to 503